# database schema for blog platform like blogspot in relational database

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, blogs, multi-tenant

I always wondered How can design database for blog platform like blogspot.
for example for posts what is good design for medium size blog platform:

1. put all posts from all blogs in one table and use something like blog_id column for them.
2. every time new blog request come create whole tables that needed in same database, and name tables like post_blogId (post_1, post_2).
3. create separate database for each blog

I think number two is better but question is a platform that has 500,000-1,000,000 blogs must have 500,000-1000,000 tables for posts and also for comments..!! does it efficient??

what about choice number 4??:
use solution 2 but for something like each 500(what this number should be??) blog create separate database.

I really have no idea which one would work efficient :(.

Comment: Your first option is almost always the correct way to go.  Databases engines are designed to handle big tables, not databases with zillions of tables.

Comment: @GordonLinoff but does it efficient that a table has 10 millions record?

Comment: Of course.  You do realize that this site runs off of relational databases.  It has more than 10 million records.

Comment: About 10% of tables have more than 10M rows.  I've seen one table with over 6 billion rows.  A trillion rows is possible.  And, yes, there would be a little more sluggishness with a trillion rows than with a mere 10 million.  Or a lot more sluggishness if you design it wrong and/or have poor indexes.